# How to Format 60 to 01m:00s in textbox?in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I already tried this code 
but nothing happens.

```
 textbox_testime.Text = String.Format("mm:ss")
```

Comment: `textbox_testime.Text = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60).ToString()` or `textbox_testime.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).ToString()` or ... `String.Format("mm:ss")` is missing the *thing* to format :)

Comment: it work but can you do 01m:00s format? or custom format?

Comment: TextBox are not well suited to show formatted data. For your task perhaps it is better to use a DateTimePicker control

Comment: Something like `myTimeSpan.ToString("mm\m\:ss\s")` i think.

Comment: If you like `String.Format`: `textbox_testime.Text = string.Format("{0:mm}m:{0:ss}s", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))`. You can interpolate it instead or pass a format to `.ToString()` or...

Comment: you got it but i can't mix this one though it's hard  `tbox_testime.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("testtime").InnerText`

Comment: If `60` is actually a string, convert it to an Integer value. See `Integer.TryParse()`. So you can also be sure you're parsing a convertible value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim value As Double
'Ensure that the user input is valid before proceeding
If Double.TryParse(textbox_testime.Text, value) Then
    'Convert the input to Timespan
    Dim time As Timespan = Timespan.FromSeconds(value)
    'Format the Timespan and update your TextBox
    textbox_testime.Text = time.ToString("mm\m\:ss\s")
Else 
    'Do something else 
End If
```

You can read up on custom timespan formatting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers don't include placeholder separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours, hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these symbols must be included in the custom format string as string literals.

The quoted text above is accomplished by using the `\` followed by the separator (string literal) of your choosing. The `\` only handles one character. As such, to format the Timespan to `01m:00s`, you need to define the separator `m:` as `\m` & `\:` while `s` is `\s`.

**ToString()**: `time.ToString()` ~> `00:01:00`
**Custom ToString()**: `time.ToString("mmss")` ~> `0100`
**Custom separated ToString()**: `time.ToString("mm\:ss")` ~> `01:00`
**Custom formatted ToString()**: `time.ToString("mm\m\:\ss\s")` ~> `01m:00s`